# How can I charge my MacBook Pro and not block one thunderbolt 3 port for other uses?

Tags: macos, hardware, thunderbolt, power

I record high school bands when they go to contest using Sound Studio.  Each of three judges is also making digital recordings on hand held recorders.

While I am recording one band through a mixer onto my Macbook using a USB port, I download the judges comments from the previous band from the hand held recorders through another USB port. I then quickly edit all four files and then write them onto a thumb drive using a USB port.

Here is the problem. I need to upgrade my current laptop (it is four years old) and turn it into my backup.  The current crop of laptops only have two thunderbolt  ports.  How do I do this work while keeping the laptop charged?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions here.  As currently written, your question is a bit vague and open-ended.  What **specifically** are you looking for?  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Apple makes a [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) which you can use to connect a USB-A thumb-drive and power the computer simultaneously. Other manufacturers make similar devices, but Apple's offering is well-made.

[image]

All sorts of hubs exist so you can pick your price point, support, features and decide if a larger, more rugged device is less likely to disconnect while the event is happening.

Comment: We purchased >100 of these adapters for the users in our work-place because they are well-made and we anticipate they will survive longer than third-party adapters which may have the same characteristics, but inferior build quality. Since you seem to be talking only about one device, this adaptor will fit the bill.